# notifyDataSetChanged not refreshing listview fragment

Tags: android, listview, fragment, notifydatasetchanged

I have searched as much as I could on google, I have search as much as I can find on here, I am seriously at a loss, my co-workers are unhelpful, i just want someone to look at this and tell me what it is I am missing that is causing the listview not to refresh the data. The Logs are showing that is is containing the correct number of elements but its not showing in the list.

```
public class ShiftListViewFragment extends Fragment {
    private static int TOTAL_ITEMS = 11;
    private static String TAG = "ShiftListViewFragment";
    private ListView mListView;
    private ShiftItemArrayAdapter mAdapter;
    private ArrayList<ShiftItem> mShiftItems = new ArrayList<ShiftItem>();
    ;
    private ArrayList<ShiftItem> displayShiftItems = new ArrayList<ShiftItem>();
    private Button mPageLeftButton;
    private Button mPageRightButton;

    private int mPageNumber = 0;
    private int mPageIndex = 0;

    public static ShiftListViewFragment newInstance() {
        ShiftListViewFragment shiftListViewFragment = new ShiftListViewFragment();

        return shiftListViewFragment;
    }

    public ShiftListViewFragment() {

    }

    public void populateShiftItems() {
        Date clockIn = new Date("08/17/2015 11:11 AM");
        Date clockOut = new Date("08/17/2015 11:11 PM");
        Date breakTimeIn = new Date("08/17/2015 10:11 PM");
        Date breakTimeOut = new Date("08/17/2015 10:11 PM");
        for (int i = 0; i < 28; i++) {
            ShiftItem shiftItem =
                    new ShiftItem(new ShiftDto(clockIn, clockOut, breakTimeIn, breakTimeOut));
            mShiftItems.add(shiftItem);
        }
    }

    public void populateDisplayShifts() {
        int lowerBound = mPageIndex * 11;
        int uppBound = lowerBound + 11;
        if (uppBound > mShiftItems.size()) {
            uppBound = mShiftItems.size();
        }
        ArrayList<ShiftItem> shifts = new ArrayList<ShiftItem>();
        for (int i = lowerBound; i < uppBound; i++) {
            shifts.add(mShiftItems.get(i));
        }
        displayShiftItems.clear();
        mAdapter.clear();
        displayShiftItems.addAll(shifts);
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public int getPageNumber() {
        int pages = 0;
        pages = mShiftItems.size() / TOTAL_ITEMS;

        if (pages % 11 != 0) {
            pages++;
        }
        Log.d("TAG", "TotalPages " + pages);
        Log.d("TAG", "Shift items count:" + mShiftItems.size());

        return pages;
    }

    private void initViews(View view) {
        mListView = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.shift_report_list);
        mPageLeftButton = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.btn_page_left);
        mPageRightButton = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.btn_page_right);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.shift_list_report_fragment, null);
        initViews(view);
        populateShiftItems();
        mPageNumber = getPageNumber();
        mAdapter = new ShiftItemArrayAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.shift_list_item,
                displayShiftItems,
                R.color.shift_list_item_bg);
        mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        populateDisplayShifts();
        mPageRightButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mPageIndex++;
                if (mPageIndex > mPageNumber - 1) {
                    mPageIndex = 0;
                }
                populateDisplayShifts();
                Log.d(TAG, "Page:" + mPageIndex + " Actual items in list:" + mAdapter.getCount());
            }
        });

        mPageLeftButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mPageIndex--;
                if (mPageIndex < 0) {
                    mPageIndex = mPageNumber - 1;
                }
                populateDisplayShifts();

                Log.d(TAG, "Page:" + mPageIndex + " Actual items in list:" + mAdapter.getCount());
            }
        });

        return view;
    }
}
```

And my adapter

```
public class ShiftItemArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ShiftItem> {
    private LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;
    private int mAlternateColorResource;

    public ShiftItemArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource,
            ArrayList<ShiftItem> shiftItems,
            @ColorRes int colorResID) {
        super(context, resource, shiftItems);
        this.mAlternateColorResource = colorResID;
        this.mLayoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    /**
     * Applies background resources in an alternating fashion, based on the view's position.
     */
    protected void applyBackground(int position, @NonNull View convertView) {
        if (position % 2 == 0) {
            convertView.setBackgroundResource(mAlternateColorResource);
        } else {
            convertView.setBackgroundResource(android.R.color.white);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder viewHolder = null;

        String clockedIn = getItem(position).getInTime();
        String clockedOut =
                getItem(position).getOutTime();

        if (convertView == null) {
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.shift_list_item, null);
            viewHolder.clockedInTextView = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.time_in);
            viewHolder.clockedOutTextView = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.time_out);
            viewHolder.dashedTextView = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.dash);
            viewHolder.breakTotalTextView = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.break_total);
            viewHolder.totalTimeTextView = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.total_time);

            viewHolder.clockedInTextView.setText(clockedIn);
            viewHolder.clockedOutTextView.setText(clockedOut);

            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
        }

        Date breaksIn = new Date("11/11/2015 11:20 AM");
        Date breaksOut = new Date("11/11/2015 12:20 PM");
        String breakHours = String.valueOf(
                DateHelper.getTimeDuration(breaksIn, breaksOut, false).getStandardHours());
        String breakMin = String.valueOf(
                DateHelper.getTimeDuration(breaksIn, breaksOut, false).getStandardMinutes());
        viewHolder.breakTotalTextView.setText(breakHours + " HR " + breakMin + " MIN ");

        applyBackground(position, convertView);

        return convertView;
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        public TextView clockedInTextView;
        public TextView dashedTextView;
        public TextView clockedOutTextView;
        public TextView breakTotalTextView;
        public TextView totalTimeTextView;
    }
}
```

Any and all help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do us (*and yourself*) a favour and reduce the code to the absolute minimum to understand the problem. You may even find the solution while doing this, because it forces you to explain the code to yourself.

Comment: is the list showing lesser items or more items?

Comment: It does add just doesnt remove and when I use clear() it not repopulate the list just for a test it changes nothing, but when i add and not clear it adds to the list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently there is a bug in Android where the list items in a listview have trouble defining their actual size, so the solution was to set the list_item.xml to a specific height instead of wrap_content.

Comment: Can you post the link where you found out that it is a bug?

Comment: Wasn't a link, just discovered it by testing it.